# MySQL "Distinct" join super slow

Tags: mysql, join, distinct

I have the following query which gives me the right results. But it's super slow.
What makes it slow is the

```
AND a.id IN (SELECT id FROM st_address GROUP BY element_id)
```

part. The query should show from which countries we get how many orders.
A person can have multiple addresses, but in this case, we only only want one.
Cause otherwise it will count the order multiple times. Maybe there is a better way to achieve this? A distinct join on the person or something?

```
SELECT cou.title_en, COUNT(co.id), SUM(co.price) AS amount
FROM customer_order co
JOIN st_person p ON (co.person_id = p.id)
JOIN st_address a ON (co.person_id = a.element_id AND a.element_type_id = 1)
JOIN st_country cou ON (a.country_id = cou.id) 
WHERE order_status_id != 7 AND a.id IN (SELECT id FROM st_address GROUP BY element_id)
GROUP BY cou.id
```

Comment: Does the customer_order table not track the delivery or billing address? Surely it's possible to get just a single address specific to each order?

Comment: Remove group by from sub query this might help

Comment: @Rory The customer_order does track the billing address. But that is often not in the country the order comes from. Most of our customers are in Europe and the order per country. But the billing center is often centralized somewhere.

Comment: @Raheel: I need the Group By to remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a faster solution. The trick is a join with a sub query:

```
JOIN (SELECT element_id, country_id, id FROM st_address WHERE element_type_id = 1 GROUP BY
```

This is the complete query:

```
SELECT cou.title_en, COUNT(o.id), SUM(o.price) AS amount 
FROM customer_order o
JOIN (SELECT element_id, country_id, id FROM st_address WHERE element_type_id = 1 GROUP BY element_id) AS a ON (o.person_id = a.element_id)
JOIN st_country cou ON (a.country_id = cou.id) 
WHERE o.order_status_id != 7 
GROUP BY cou.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to replace the IN with an EXISTS?

```
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM st_address b WHERE a.id = b.id)
```

The EXISTS part should stop the subquery as soon as the first row matching the condition is found.  I have read conflicting comments on if this is actually happening though so you might throw a limit 1 in there to see if you get any gain.

Comment: That is indeed much faster, but it still counts every address.

Comment: No, it doesn't if you remove the Join to the address table - and keep only this Exists subquery.